# How do you get the Web Audio API to work on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've made a web app which plays 16 audio tracks together in a loop using the Web Audio API and vanilla JavaScript. So far it works on desktop in Safari, Chrome and Firefox and on android devices. It doesn't, however, work on iPhone or iPad.

The starting of the audio context is triggered by clicking a "start" button on the page which then displays the controls (a play button and a mute button for each of the 16 tracks).

On iPhone, the page fails to load past the starting screen so I presume that the audio context is failing to start although I'm unsure as to why this is. I've read on a previous post that this is something to do with iOS not allowing for an audio context to start unless triggered by the user. A start button on the page, I thought would be sufficient as a workaround but unfortunately this has not worked.

Any expertise on the web-audio API would be greatly appreciated!

```
  constructor(context, urlList, callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urlList = urlList;
    this.onload = callback;
    this.bufferList = [];
    this.loadCount = 0;
  }
  loadBuffer = (url, index) => {
    // Load buffer asynchronously
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    const loader = this;

    request.onload = function() {
      // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
      loader.context.decodeAudioData(
        request.response,
        function(buffer) {
          if (!buffer) {
            alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
            return;
          }
          loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
          if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
            loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
          loadingScreen.style.display = 'none';
          loadedContent.style.display = 'block';
        },
        function(error) {
          console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
        }
      );
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
    };

    request.send();
  };
  load = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
      this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
  };
}

//INIT

// Keep track of all loaded buffers.
const buffers = {};
// Page-wide audio context.
let context = null;

const trackRef = {
  rhodes: { bufferToLoad: './audio/rhodes.mp3', muteRef: muteRhodes },
  rhodes2: { bufferToLoad: './audio/rhodes2.mp3', muteRef: muteRhodes2 },
  conga: { bufferToLoad: './audio/conga.mp3', muteRef: muteConga },
  kick: { bufferToLoad: './audio/kick.mp3', muteRef: muteKick },
  clap: { bufferToLoad: './audio/clap.mp3', muteRef: muteClap },
  snare: { bufferToLoad: './audio/snare.mp3', muteRef: muteSnare },
  ohh: { bufferToLoad: './audio/ohh.mp3', muteRef: muteOhh },
  chh: { bufferToLoad: './audio/chh.mp3', muteRef: muteChh },
  piano: { bufferToLoad: './audio/piano.mp3', muteRef: mutePiano },
  bass1: { bufferToLoad: './audio/bass1.mp3', muteRef: muteBass1 },
  bass2: { bufferToLoad: './audio/bass2.mp3', muteRef: muteBass2 },
  vox1: { bufferToLoad: './audio/vox1.mp3', muteRef: muteVox1 },
  vox2: { bufferToLoad: './audio/vox2.mp3', muteRef: muteVox2 },
  vox3: { bufferToLoad: './audio/vox3.mp3', muteRef: muteVox3 },
  vox4: { bufferToLoad: './audio/vox4.mp3', muteRef: muteVox4 },
  vox5: { bufferToLoad: './audio/vox5.mp3', muteRef: muteVox5 }
};

const tracks = Object.keys(trackRef);

// console.log(buffersToLoad);

// Loads all sound samples into the buffers object.
function loadBuffers() {
  // Array-ify
  const trackNames = [];
  const paths = [];
  for (let trackName in trackRef) {
    const path = trackRef[trackName].bufferToLoad;
    trackNames.push(trackName);
    paths.push(path);
  }
  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(context, paths, function(bufferList) {
    for (let i = 0; i < bufferList.length; i++) {
      const buffer = bufferList[i];
      const trackName = trackNames[i];
      buffers[trackName] = buffer;
    }
  });
  bufferLoader.load();
}

const setUpAudioContext = () => {
  try {
    // Fix up prefixing
    const AudioContext = (window.AudioContext =
      window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    context = new AudioContext();
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Web Audio API not supported in this browser');
  }
  loadBuffers();
};

// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpAudioContext);

startButton.addEventListener('click', setUpAudioContext);
```

Comment: Can you connect with the Safari Web Inspector and see what is logged in the console?

Comment: have you tried a "webkit" version of the context for IOS?  re:  https://github.com/GersonRosales/Record-Audios-and-Videos-with-getUserMedia/blob/master/example_3.html#L35